# (GitHub push) Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Tags: github, version-control

I am trying to push to a repository that unfortunately got severed from my client terminal in my text editor.

The error that comes up is:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/jboyle1/milestoneproject-004.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I try and:

```
git pull repo_name
```

but it says:

```
remote: Repository not found.
```

Its probably a simple fix but I'm struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simply `git pull` (or `git pull origin master`)

Check the output of `git remote -v`, and see if "`origin`" does reference the remote repository URL.

Comment: @JEDBOYLE Then you can change origin URL with `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<you>/<the-right-repo>`